# join strings in JS

Tags: javascript, string

I have an array `A` and array `B`:

```
A = ["1234","5678","4444"]
B = 7868,9090
```

I want array `C` to be:

```
C = ["1234","5678","4444","7868","9090"]
```

The length of array `A` and `B` can vary and array `B` should join the end of array `A`.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried using push() but I'm still having problems.

Thank you.

---

I did the following to solve the issue

```
B = JSON.stringify(B);   
A = A.concat(B);     
A = A.replace('][', ',');
```

Comment: _"What is the best way to do this?"_ - to first of all learn enough of the basics to know that these are not strings, but arrays ...

Comment: Please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post code you have tried that is giving you problems. Also see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A is an array of string. And B is also an array of integers but you are forgetting braces or brackets around it.

Comment: I inherited this project and A and B are received as shown. That's way I need to have the result/array C.

Comment: B isn't valid javascript. How is it actually output? Is it a string ("7868,9090") or an array ([7868,9090]) or what?

Comment: @Gnam If B is received as shown as `B = 7868,9090` instead of `B = "7868,9090"` you have bigger problems as that causes a syntax error. If you already tried `push` can you post your code? Also, look into `split` and `concat` and try out what could work. Post the code you have issues with if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Agree.  This isn't even valid Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get the result I need:

```
B = JSON.stringify(B);   
A = A.concat(B);     
A = A.replace('][', ',');
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion

```
A.concat(B.split(','));
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you mean with `B = 7868,9090`? That is incorrect JavaScript and produces a syntax error when trying to run it.

How to produce output `["1234", "5678", "4444", "7868", "9090"]` depends on what is actually the correct input value for `B`. Depending on whether `B` is an array of integers, an array of strings or a comma separated string, you'll need to take a different approach.

## If B is an array of integers

Can I assume you mean `var B = [7868,9090];`, meaning that B is an array of integers? In that case the simplest way to get the expected result, would be to do this :

```
var result = A.concat(B.map(function(x) {return "" + x;}));
```

#### Explanation

- [**`var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example) allows you to merge `arr1` and `arr2` and output the result to `arr3`
- [**`var arr2 = arr1.map(f(x))`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) allows you to loop through all elements `x` of `arr1` and output the outcome of function `f` to `arr2`
- **`var y = "" + x`** allows you to convert an integer value `x` and output it to `y`

#### Demo

```js
var A = ["1234","5678","4444"];
var B = [7868,9090];

var result = A.concat(B.map(function(x) {return "" + x;}));

console.log(result);
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f7s5o4m5/4/).

---

## If B is an array of strings

If `var B = ["7868","9090"];` is actually the correct input, you don't need the `var arr2 = arr1.map(f(x))` and `var y = "" + x` bits and you can just do this :

```
var result = A.concat(B);
```

---

## If B is a comma separated string

If `var B = "7868,9090";` is actually the correct input, you don't need the `var arr2 = arr1.map(f(x))` and `var y = "" + x` bits either, but you will need to split `B` into an array :

```
var result = A.concat(B.split(','));
```

Answer (score -1):

For copying an array to another you can use ES6 **Spread** syntax

```
var A = ["1234","5678","4444"];
var B = ["7868","9090"];
var C = [...A, ...B];
console.log(C);
// C will become [1234","5678","4444","7868","9090"];
```

[For, how to use Spread syntax follow this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Correct way of declaring a string and concatnating it:

```
var str_a="123,124";
var str_b ="125,126";
var str_ab= str_a + str_b;
console.log(str_ab);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming B is also an array, you can make use of the ES6 spread function:

```
A = ["1234","5678","4444"];
B = ["7868","9090"];
C = [...A, ...B]
```

which gives `C = ["1234","5678","4444", "7868","9090"]`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator for more information and https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator for more examples of the spread operator